# Two members being dependent on each other?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Imagine having a class called `Node` that can hold multiple parents and multiple children:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        virtual void addParent(Node *parent);
        virtual void addChild(Node *child);
    private:
        vector<Node*> m_parents;
        vector<Node*> m_children;
};
```

The problem is that every time you add a parent to a node, the node's `m_parents` must be updated and the parent's `m_children` must be updated; this creates an infinite loop.

```
void Node::addParent(Node *parent)
{
    if (m_parents.lacks(parent)) { // supposing such method exists
        m_parents.push_back(parent);
    }
    parent->addChild(this);
}

void Node::addChild(Node *child)
{
    if (m_children.lacks(child)) {
        m_children.push_back(child);
    }
    child->addParent(this);
}
```

As you can see, it's no good.
I've managed to solve this by having four methods for adding instead of two, but it feels somewhat stupid.
The additional two methods are both declared `private` or `protected` so they can't be called by others.
Here's the original `addParent` and a new method called `rawAddChild`:

```
void Node::addParent(Node *parent)
{
    if (m_parents.lacks(parent)) {
        m_parents.push_back(parent);
    }
    parent->rawAddChild(this);
}

void Node::rawAddChild(Node *child)
{
    if (m_children.lacks(child)) {
        m_children.push_back(child);
    }
    // Doesn't call for parent's method
}
```

This would obviously be the same for `addChild()` and `rawAddParent()`.

However, this doesn't feel like a proper solution, and it's certainly not clear for "outsiders" why there's `addChild` and `rawAddChild` methods.
Is there a problem with my logic and if so, how should I solve such problem? Or is my solution already good?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest doing the actual operation in only one of the two methods:

```
void Node::addParent(Node *parent)
{
    if (m_parents.lacks(parent)) {
        m_parents.push_back(parent);
    }
    if (parent->m_children.lacks(this)) {
        parent->m_children.push_back(this);
    }
}

void Node::addChild(Node *child)
{
    child->addParent(this);
}
```

Comment: Note that you could even get rid of the near-useless one, leaving your code with one method instead of four. woo!

Comment: I was about to suggest your solution, but I noticed that "addParent" and "addChild" are virtual. What if a derived class has some special behavior when adding a child? I would suggest one modification to your answer, which is: make "addParent" and "addChild" non-virtual, and if needed, add "onParentAdded" and "onChildAdded" virtual methods which derived classes may choose to implement.

Comment: I'm assuming `Node` is not meant to be used in a polymorphic context and that the `virtual` specifiers are not here for any particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would test if the vector already constains the element (probably using set instead of vector)

```
void Node::addParent(Node *parent)
{
    if (m_parents.lacks(parent)) { // supposing such method exists
        m_parents.push_back(parent);
    }
    if (parent->m_childs.find(this)==set::end)
        parent->addChild(this);
}

void Node::addChild(Node *child)
{
    if (m_children.lacks(child)) {
        m_children.push_back(child);
    }
    if (child->m_parents.find(this)==set::end)
        child->addParent(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should abstract a little.

```
bool Node::addParent(Node *parent)
{
    if (m_parents.lacks(parent)) { // supposing such method exists
        m_parents.push_back(parent);
        parent->updateRelationShip(parent,this);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Node::addChild(Node *child)
{
    if (m_children.lacks(child)) {
        m_children.push_back(child);
        child->updateRelationShip(this,child); 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void Node::updateRelationship(Node*parent, Node* child){
   parent->addChild(child);
   child->addParent(parent);
}
```

Comment: Note I'm half sleep so not completely sure if there is a circular reference, but you get the idea....